# Why is the genealogy in Ruth different from Luke?

Tags: luke, translation-philosophy, genealogy, ruth

In [Ruth 4:18-22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ruth%204&version=ESV), the genealogy recorded is different from Luke [Luke 3:23-38](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%203&version=ESV).

> Now these are the generations of Perez: Perez fathered Hezron, 19 Hezron fathered Ram, Ram fathered Amminadab, 20 Amminadab fathered Nahshon, Nahshon fathered Salmon, 21 Salmon fathered Boaz, Boaz fathered Obed, 22 Obed fathered Jesse, and Jesse fathered David.

> David, 32 the son of Jesse, the son of Obed, the son of Boaz, the son of Sala, the son of Nahshon, 33 the son of Amminadab, the son of Admin, the son of Arni, the son of Hezron, the son of Perez

In Ruth, Boaz is the son of Salmon, and Amminadab is the son of of Ram, in Luke, Boaz is the son of Sala, Amminadab is the son of Admin, **and gives an extra Arni.**

Comment: [Luke's Gospel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_Luke), along with the rest of the [New Testament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Testament), was written in Greek; as such, it usually quotes directly from the [Greek Septuagint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint), rather than retranslating the [Masoretic text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoretic_Text). All Greek scripture (both Testaments), canonical or otherwise, along with other early Christian writings, can be found [here](http://www.greekdoc.com); note that each Greek word is linked, to provide grammar and explanation.

Comment: Are you going to tell us _how_ it is different (in your opinion) or do we have to figure it out for ourselves ? Some clarity and detail would be useful, please.

Comment: "Sala" is the English translation of Luke's Greek translation of the Hebrew name, and "Salmon" is the English translation of Ruth's Hebrew.  They could easily be the same person.  The significant question is why, given that he would have been familiar with the Book of Ruth, does Luke list *Arni and Admin*, where Ruth lists only *Ram*?

Comment: Why is the question downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I've read and heard from multiple sources that the authors sometimes skip generations.  
The Scriptures merely say that Jesus would be son of David. 
Also, isn't it possible or likely that there are multiple lines from Ruth to David, which is the specific generations one might expect an overlap.  Having multiple lines of genealogy from David to Jesus would certainly fulfill the prophecies on the subject.

Comment: Please include the actual texts and elaborate on what you see as disceprancies.

Comment: @BlackWatch asks "*Why is the question downvoted?*". Get used to it. Even excellent questions will receive down-votes for no apparent reason. We all get them. (e.g.. A month ago, one of my answers got 3 downvotes and no upvotes.) ¶ In this case though, it might be because the question lacks details. It would have helped if it had included full quotations of the two relevant scriptures, and if it had explicitly listed the specific details of the "different" parts. If the readers have to look something up to understand what is being asked, that definitely hurts the quality of the question.

Comment: The focus is on "Arni", correct? Who is Arni - Since 1 Chronicles 2 also does not mention Arni.

Comment: No, the other names are also important to give an explanation, not just Arni. But you guys gave an explanation, now just Arni is unexplained.

Comment: Supposedly ESV found its reference to Ἀρνὶ Arni in the following Greek Manuscripts of the NT: UBS Greek New Testament (5th corrected ed.); Novum Testamentum Graece (28th ed., 2012). - as mentioned in my update.

Answer (score 1):

**Why do we read "the son of Arni" in the ESV Genealogy of Boaz from Luke 3:33, since **Ἀρνὶ** (Arni) is NOT listed as a son of חֶצְר֖וֹן Chetzron (Hezron) in Ruth 4:19 or 1 Chronicles 2:9**?**

We find the LXX also does not include "son of Arni" in the Greek genealogy:

> "Luk 3:33 [LXX] - **Which was the son of Aminadab, which was the son of Aram, which was the son of Esrom, which was the son of Phares, which was the son of Juda**," ( 3:33  τοῦ Ἀμιναδὰβ τοῦ Ἀράμ, τοῦ Ἑσρὼμ τοῦ Φάρες τοῦ Ἰούδα )

- In Ruth 4:19, Amminadab is the son of Ram - not Arni, as stated in the MT : "And Chetzron begot Ram, and Ram begot Amminadav." ( וְחֶצְרוֹן֙ הוֹלִ֣יד אֶת־רָ֔ם וְרָ֖ם הוֹלִ֥יד אֶת־עַמִּֽינָדָֽב )
- So where in the Bible does ESV find רָ֔ם Ram as a "son of Arni" to splice up the genealogy in Luke 3:33?

**1 Chronicles 2:9** states Chetzron had only 3 sons :

> "And the sons of Chetzron, who were born to him Yerachmeel, [and Ram], and Keluvai." ( וּבְנֵ֥י חֶצְר֖וֹן אֲשֶׁ֣ר נֽוֹלַד־ל֑וֹ אֶת־יְרַחְמְאֵ֥ל וְאֶת־רָ֖ם וְאֶת־כְּלוּבָֽי )

- Wait!!! - Chronicler, where's Ram's father Arni from Luke 3:33?
- ESV where are you getting your Arni? | GRK: Ἀδμὶν τοῦ Ἀρνὶ τοῦ Ἑσρὼμ - Mysterious one time occurrence known as Strong's 689 [https://biblehub.com/greek/strongs_689.htm].

**Supposedly ESV found its reference to Ἀρνὶ Arni in the following Greek Manuscripts of the NT: UBS Greek New Testament (5th corrected ed.); Novum Testamentum Graece (28th ed., 2012).**

---

Translation Issue : **Are the genealogies of Boaz in Luke 3:32-38 LXX/ESV different from Ruth 4:18-22 MT ?** - Due to poorly transliterated names, Boaz' genealogy in the ESV translation of [Luke 3:32] may appear different (like Boaz son of Sala, instead of Boaz son of Salmon). - **In Ruth 4:20-21, Salmah שַׂלְמָֽה (Robe) becomes שַׂלְמוֹן֙ Salmon (Paid).**

In MT - Ruth 4:20 states : "And Amminadab begot Nahshon, and **Nahshon begot [Salmah]**." ( וְעַמִּֽינָדָב֙ הוֹלִ֣יד אֶת־נַחְשׁ֔וֹן וְנַחְשׁ֖וֹן הוֹלִ֥יד אֶת־שַׂלְמָֽה )

In MT - Ruth 4:21 states: "**And [Salmon] begot Boaz**, and Boaz begot Obed." ( וְשַׂלְמוֹן֙ הוֹלִ֣יד אֶת־בֹּ֔עַז וּבֹ֖עַז הוֹלִ֥יד אֶת־עוֹבֵֽד )

- Wait!!! - Why did Salmah (Robe) become שַׂלְמוֹן֙ Salmon (Paid) , in Ruth 4:21?** The [Robe] now [Paid]... for the redemption of Ruth.

**In LXX - We notice the author of Luke 3:32 chose the final [Paid] version of Salmon from Ruth 4:21**, stating :

> "Which was the son of Jesse, which was the son of Obed, which was the son of [Booz], which was the son of [Salmon], which was the son of [Naasson]," ( 3:32  τοῦ Ἰεσσαὶ τοῦ Ὠβήδ, τοῦ Βόοζ, τοῦ Σαλμών, τοῦ Ναασσὼν )

The LXX is highlighting this genealogy has [Paid] for someone's redemption.

However - **In the ESV - The Father of Boaz is even less accurately transliterated, stating : "32 the son of Jesse, the son of Obed, the son of [Boaz, the son of Sala], the son of Nahshon,".** ...aaah, oh no!

- ESV, you chose the previously Salmah from Ruth 4:20 instead, and removed his mem / Ivrit meaning of [Robe]... no longer allowing readers to enjoy the poetic narrative of Hebrew names.
- ESV, please give Salmah his mem & hei back, to redeem his meaning whole as a mantle or "robe" from [in] which [strength] comes aka בּעַז "Bo-az", if you choose to use Salmah instead of Salmon.

Comment: Nice, and where Arni from Luke comes from? He doesn't appear anywhere on the Hebrew Bible.